# get only the first 20 items in a backbone collection

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js

I'm trying to render only the first 20 items in a backbonejs collection.

If the collection was an array I would do _.first(collection, 20). But since it's not it doesn't work. How do I limit it to 20? Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Backbone collections have underscore methods [builtin](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods):

```
collection.first(20)
```

Comment: @Harry you can, but not easily... try this underscore method: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#chain