# Backbone.js Collection filter top 10 models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

my Collection fetches a few records and I have to show only top 10 records from it. I attempted

```
   this.collection.each(function(){
        if (count == 10) break;
        //pass model to view
   });
```

unfortunately **break** does not work with each() API of underscore.js
Refer here: [how to break the _.each function in underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779799/how-to-break-the-each-function-in-underscore-js)

How do I write a filter to pluck only top 10 from the collection

```
     this.collection.filter();
```

UPDATE: collection.first(10) fetched me filtered list. However, I still needed to chain .each() to this collection to process the collection items. collection.first() does not allow chain. Please refer to my selected answer for solution to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get only the first 20 items in a backbone collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240382/get-only-the-first-20-items-in-a-backbone-collection)

Comment: @muistooshort I see this is an exact duplicate.Thanks for pointing it out. I have received partial solution to my question. I am amending this question so that I can get help on the rest of it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E.g.

```
this.collection.first(10)
```

Then, if you need to work with each model, e.g. :

```
    var collection = new Backbone.Collection([{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5}],{model: Backbone.Model});

    var newCollection = new Backbone.Collection(collection.first(2));

    newCollection.each(function(model){
      alert(JSON.stringify(model.toJSON()));
    });
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8JNE/1).
​
Note that there is another way to do it with the [Underscore chain method](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#chain) as said in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240382/get-only-the-first-20-items-in-a-backbone-collection).

Have a look at [Backbone doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) and [Underscore doc](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#first).

Comment: first() in underscore.js is array function and this is a Collection. I tried using it and browser throws up at that very line saying: Object doesnt support this property or method...thanks for your answer!

Comment: Anyway, it should work for a Collection. There is another topic on stackoverlow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240382/get-only-the-first-20-items-in-a-backbone-collection. A lot of underscore methods also work for Backbone Collection, just removing the first argument (array) and calling the method from the Backbone Collection object.

Comment: I second xiris, take a look at this fiddle (look in the console) http://jsfiddle.net/RgBVw/

Comment: @JensAlm I was trying to do: collection.first(2).each(function(model){
    alert(model.toJSON());
}); but it throws me that error: http://jsfiddle.net/RgBVw/3/

Comment: @xiris thanks...I see from your link that it does not allow chaining.. which is why I am getting that error

Comment: Else, you can use the Underscore chain method (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#chain) as said in the other topic.

Comment: @xiris excellent! that works for me...Can you please edit your answer to incorporate the solution you provided in the fiddle. I will mark your solution as answer to my question....thanks for following up!